# How to balance pressure in a multi-zone damper hvac with an always on bypass valve

Tags: hvac, central-heating, central-air

### Background

I'm the new owner of a multi-family home where the previous owner was a large corporation that made money by overspending on renovations.  Thus, they tended to renovate with top-tier equipment over-spec'd equipment, and lots of options, but I noticed some basic misconfigurations that needed to be fixed.

### Issue

The primary issue is that I have multi-zone central heating and air-conditioning system that does not adequately heat/cool the zones at the front of the building (let's call that zone 1, the master bedroom).  The zones don't seem to be effective with the multiple dampers because the bypass is always on bleeding pressure and one of the dampers is always open - was this done on purpose by design or is this a mistake?   Can I increase the bypass weight to close that valve so that the pressure is delivered through to the front of the house... and if so how do I know if that is safe and not over pressured?

I did a test by opening all the valves and turning on all the zones/fans and even that still triggered the lightweight bypass.

The bypass is right on top of the stack in the main trunk vent and the pressure does seem to be pretty high when it blows through the valve.  Do I need to test for obstructions/friction in the further vents as well?  I didn't notice anything and when I closed the register in the living room that is always on - the pressure to zone 1 jumped up and was adequate which leads me to think there is no obstruction.

### Observations

- The first floor has 3 zones and when you call for heat in zone 1 (the master bedroom) at the front of the house, most of the flow goes into the two rear zones: zone 2 (the kitchen/living room) and zone 3 (the guest bedroom) both located right above the blower in the basement and at the back of the house.
- Dampers to zone 1 seems to work fine, however of the 2 dampers to zone 2, only one of them seems to work - the small kick panel to the kitchen.  The large main living room damper always remains open even though it does look to be wired to something.  Zone 3, the guest bedroom never fully closes or opens and seems to only partially close or partially open.
- Thus zone 1 only gets very anemic air and is never warm enough, whereas the rest of the floor is sweltering.
- There is also a small hallway vent that doesn't get much air and always seems to be on low flow
- The floor below the rear bedroom is always warm, that's because the bypass valve is always activated anytime the system is on, whether all zones are open or not, the small amount of counterweight never closes the bypass valve.  The bypass vents directly into an open 10" pipe vent that points halfway into the basement ceiling rafter space and halfway into the mechanical room. Thus, it heats the ceiling and whatever else is in the ceiling gap whenever the heat is on.  At a minimum do we need to point that vent back down into the mechanical room rather than into the ceiling?

### Other Questions

Mainly on how to balance the pressure and understand if the bypass valve was so lightly sprung on purpose.

- How do I make sure the system is not over-pressured?  I'm tempted to adjust the bypass with more weights, but I'm afraid that they set it to that light weight for a reason.  However, it's always bypass venting, even when all vents are on.  Seems wasteful.
- Is there a way to test or analyze if I would be over-pressuring the system if I modify these damper settings or bypass valve settings?  I don't want to break the furnace and I'm a novice.
- Why is the living room damper wired but never activated, did they
  purposely keep it off?
- Can I wire up both living room and kitchen to the same damper?

### Equipment

- 3 Ton 2-stage Rheem Prestige R96V
- Rheem RCFL-HM2417CC - 2 Ton 17" Multi-Position Cased Coil
- automatic dampers
- Honeywell HZ432

### Photos

[image]
[image: Guest-Closed]
[image: Guest-Open]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfYN4.jpg)
[image]
[image]
[image]